# Excel formula - want to return a specific value if a duplicate value is in the lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the below table I want to populate the BCA_Answer column based upon the BCA column.

Where an APP in BCA column appears more than once (e.g. APP1) I want to return the value of the Answer column in the BCA_Answer field, but the Answer value N needs to be populated if the APP appears multiple times and has answer Y and N in:

```
BCA Server  Answer  BCA_Answer
APP1    SERV1   Y   
APP1    SERV2   N   
APP2    SERV3   N   
APP3    SERV3   N   
APP3    SERV4   Y   
APP4    SERV5   Y
```

I have tried vlookups and arrays but not sure what to do. This needs to be in excel for users, and not in a database even though that would be easier.

Please see the descired results in the BCA_Answer column.

****************DESIRED OUTPUT BELOW***************

APP1 is repeated twice, and has values Y and N, but the lookup takes the value N in the BCA_Answer column and not Y.

```
BCA Server  Answer  BCA_Answer
APP1    SERV1   Y   N
APP1    SERV2   N   N
APP2    SERV3   N   
APP3    SERV3   N   
APP3    SERV4   Y   
APP4    SERV5   Y
```

Comment: Why is there nothing in `BCA_Answer` for `APP3`?

Comment: That will be populated by the formula I am asking help for, if you can help kindly just focus on the example for APP1 it would be appreciated

Comment: That table is supposed to show your desired output.  Your explanation is not clear to me, which is why I asked for that information.  What if there are more than 2 matching APPs?

Comment: Ok sure, if there are multiple APPs then the answer N take precidence over the Y, so if APP1 appears 2 or more times and has values Y or N in answer then N needs to populated in BCA_Answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to

***Edit:  Simplified***

- show nothing if the APP is singular
- show "Y" if the APP has duplicates and ALL Answers are Y
- show "N" if the APP has duplicates and any Answer is N

That being the case:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF([BCA],[@BCA])=1,[@Answer]=""),"",IF(COUNTIFS([BCA],[@BCA],[Answer],"N"),"N","Y"))
```

should do that.  Note that I used a table and a formula with structured references so as to not have to be concerned about changing cell ranges.  You can substitute the appropriate range references if you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is what I was looking for but I am not familiar with using a table so would you be able to add range references, this will help my understand the formula.

Comment: @RyanB  You can do that.  Read about structured references online for general help.  For this particular table, what you need to know is that `[BCA]` and `[Answers]` refer to the entire data area of the respective columns. e.g. in the picture above, it might be `A2:A12` and `C2:C12` if the table started in `A1`.  The `[@..]` means to refer to the single cell on the same row in the particular column named. (eg: `A2` or `C2` for the formula in `D2`, But by using structured references, you don't have to adjust the ranges when you add/delete rows